# How do you set qpdfview display options in a bash script?

Tags: pdf, bash-scripting, presentations

**Pseudocode:**

```
qpdfview **--continuous --2page-w-cover --zoom=167%** document-one.pdf#54 
 (or document-one.pdf#src:foobar.tex:42:0) & disown

printf ' \n \n Some nice message \n \n '

read -p "Press enter to continue"

qpdfview **--continuous --2page --zoom=35%** document-two.pdf#73 
(or document-two.pdf#src:foobar.tex:31:0) & disown
```

**Use Case:**

I'm presenting some documents at a meeting using `qpdfview` .

Each document requires different display settings and a bit of adjustment to be displayed correctly.

I want to specify the bolded parameters above in my bash script to keep the presentation visually seamless.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I've read `man qpdfview` in it's entirety and it does not include such options explicitly.

In the absence of such explicit options, I can only imagine it might be possible via some elaborate script to edit the configuration files each time before loading every single document. (And I'd have to figure out how to do that if it's even possible...)

Or maybe I could contact the developers?...

I'm hoping someone out there can offer some suggestions.

**Update:   Problem Partially Solved**

https://answers.launchpad.net/qpdfview/+question/404494  mentioned a "per-file setting" option that sounded promising and `man qpdfview` gave the location of the qpdfview.config file.

I made the following change to my `~/.config/qpdfview/qpdfview.config` file: `restorePerFileSettings=true`
and that seems to be preserving the view settings without me needing to specify them each time.

**The remaining problem is:**

What will I do when it's a different machine I'm presenting on?

And is there a way to quickly copy these per-file settings over to that machine at the start of the presentation?

Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe just make a bunch of screenshots? https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/is_it_worth_the_time.png

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and ideas! I think I found the solution which I'll be updating shortly.

Comment: *a partial solution, at least.